# Remove the escape sequence '\' from string to convert it to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, escaping

I have a web service which returns a struct object, so I get the response as the following XML string. Now I need to load it into XmlDocument object but how do I get rid of the escape sequences in the string. The '\' with every '"' is causing error.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<Quote xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">
<price>19656</price>
</Quote>
```

Comment: Do you see this response in debugger?

Answer (score 23):

Use [Regex.Unescape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
String unescapedString = Regex.Unescape(textString);
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to use Regex.Unescape method.

```
String unescapedString = Regex.Unescape(textString);
```

However, becareful that the [Regex.Unescape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't un-escape `"`.  According to the documentation, it does the following:

> ..by removing the escape character ("") from each character escaped
> by the method. These include the , *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #,
> and white space characters. In addition, the Unescape method unescapes
> the closing bracket (]) and closing brace (}) characters.

Comment: While this is a useful clarification, it isn't an answer to the question, but rather a critique of the top-voted answer.

Answer (score 3):

So the webservice is returning the string with actual backslashes in it? If so, I would say there's a problem with that webservice you're using, but you should be able to get around it by doing this:

```
xmlStr = xmlStr.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try escaping in verbatim strings

```
xmlStr= xmlStr.Contains("\\") ? xmlStr.Replace("\\", @"\"") : xmlStr;
```